# how i insert image name in current logged in user's account?

Tags: php, mysql

When i am using this script image name inserted in all user's row. how can i insert in current session user's line

**auth.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]) ){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

**home.php**

```
    <?php

include("php-includes/auth.php");  



//Include database configuration file
include_once 'php-includes/dbConfig.php';

//Get current user ID from session
$userId = $_SESSION["username"];

//Get user data from database
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $userId");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//User profile picture
$userPicture = !empty($row['picture'])?$row['picture']:'no-image.png';
$userPictureURL = 'uploads/images/'.$userPicture;


?>
```

Comment: `/*Get current user ID from session*/
            $userId = 'username';` that's not from a session, that's a static value. You need to start the session first, at the top of your page, by `session_start()`, then you can fetch whichever elements is in the `$_SESSION` array. How you set that variable, we have no  idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just two modifications and you are done:

1) You have to get current user's name from session

```
$userId = $_SESSION['username'];
```

2) Add single quote to the `username` value in query.

```
$update = $db->query("UPDATE user SET picture = '".$fileName."' WHERE username = '$userId'");
```

**As a note:**

> If you are providing a value to database query, if it is non-numeric,
>   you need to add single quotes to it.
>
> This tells that the passed string is a value and not any MySQL
>   reserved word/Database name/Table name/Field name.

Answer (score 0):

When user logged in on that you must keep their `username` in session for that you can use code something like given below...

```
<?php
session_start();
//retrive username from database and then save in session
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

And when you reach to this script where you need to insert the image for that user
Here can get the username from a session like given below...

```
session_start();
$userId = $_SESSION['username'];
```

And then use it in your MySQL query

```
$update = $db->query("UPDATE user SET picture = '$fileName' WHERE username = '$userId'");
```

Also, keep in mind when you are using a double quote (") for the database query then you don't need to use dots around variable name. The rather single quotation mark is enough

The complete code is given below...

```
if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
    //Include database configuration file
    include_once 'php-includes/dbConfig.php';

    //File uplaod configuration
    $result = 0;
    $uploadDir = "uploads/images/";
    $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
    $targetPath = $uploadDir. $fileName;

    //Upload file to server
    if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)){
         session_start();
        //Get current user ID from session
        $userId = $_SESSION['username'];
        $update = $db->query("UPDATE user SET picture = '$fileName' WHERE username = '$userId'");

        //Update status
        if($update){
            $result = 1;
        }
    }

    //Load JavaScript function to show the upload status
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.window.completeUpload(' . $result . ',\'' . $targetPath . '\');</script>  ';
}
```

Comment: @aditya i have updated my answer. Now please try it. I hope it works.

Comment: i have started one session already in login please check my updated code

Comment: when i am adding your code i get error that one session started already

Comment: @aditya please copy past error in your post, so that i can suggest you solution of that